# Replace a number using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code and I would like to replace the numbers inside the brackets using regular expressions.

Can someone help me?

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="inc[1].a">Counterparty</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inc[1].a" 
           name="inc[1].a" placeholder="Enter Counterparty">
</div>
```

I know how to get the strings and I would like just to replace the numbers.

For example: I would like to replace number 1 from: **inc[1](http://jsfiddle.net/gpe60ya4/).a** in order to get **inc[0].a**.

Hint: I think this page might be helpful. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Here's an attempt to replace: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpe60ya4/)

Comment: is this html stored in a string? how are you accessing the code above?

Comment: I have it in a string and jquery element.

Comment: have you tried any js, can you include your attempt?

Comment: Why do you need regexp here?? `s.replace('[1]', '[0]')`???

Comment: Because 1 and 0 are just examples. It can be ANY number instead of 1 and can be replaced with a variable number

Comment: so you want to replace whatever is in brackets with some variable number? `s.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, '['+myValue+']')`

Comment: Yeah.. the hint is good.. Have you tried?

Comment: I think I will need some more help. http://jsfiddle.net/gpe60ya4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fiddle is wrong in several places:

1. You can't have line breaks inside literal strings in javascript (So I removed them).
2. You don't need to wrap a string as a jQuery object if you want to manipulate it (So I removed that as well).
3. In order for the replace to be noticeable, you need to put some value other than '1', since that's what the string has in the first place (So changed it to '6').
4. Since you want to replace multiple occurrences of the match, you need to use the "Global" flag for the RegExp object (So I added `/.../g`)

And now it's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/gpe60ya4/1/)